# Is it possible for two exe's to access the same object in memory from a DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, dll

I have a requirement where two separate applications need to access and modify an object contained in a DLL (all control logic for the application is written in C++ and operates from a DLL). A UI exe (with minimal logic, written in C++) consumes this DLL and interacts with the main control logic DLL. I am looking to add an additional exe (written in C#) to run multiple web based services that would also need to access the same object contained in the DLL.

Comment: Anything is possible given enough time, money and leptons.

Comment: When you say the "same object" do they need to see each other's changes, or specifically work independently?

Comment: The DLL contains a very large application that an exe can interact with through a pub/sub broker. I would need access to that Broker object from both exe's so that they can access the same data.

Comment: Is your question about how to share data between two applications? If so shared memory might be one approach but there are many ways of doing this (queues, files, APIs, etc). You cannot share data by loading a common dll.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's called Shared Memory. The dll needs to call [CreateFileMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createfilemappinga) to allocate the region of memory to be shared. Then call [MapViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) to well.. map the file into memory. Then multiple processes can access this mapped memory through its name.

Comment: I have looked into this but it is my understanding that you can not simply map an entire object to shared memory, correct? The data generated by this object would constantly be updated and would need to be read by both applications at the same time.

Comment: You technically could map an entire object into shared memory if that's what you really want to do but this becomes a little more complex because you then have to learn about the windows portable file format and this technique is typically used in "shady" applications. But I think what you want to do is just load a dll and have the dll map the memory.. This can be done without a dll too but in essence a single process can not load the same instance of a dll from another process it would be two seperate instances

Comment: But yes a shared memory region mapped by any process or dll can be accessed by other processes/dlls

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question about c++ per se but about how your operating system deals with shared libraries. From my experience in looking at the application loader behavior on Solaris systems, **the answer is no**. I presume the behavior of Solaris is followed by Windows, Linux, etc. but I suppose there could be an exotic operating system that does just want you ask for (I'm looking at you QNX).

Basically if you create a global variable, let's say:

```
int foo = 5;
```

and compile your dll and analyze the content of your dll, you would see foo included in some read/write data section.

Since the section is read/write, when the exe starts and loads the dll, the operating system would create a copy of that section for the exe. Now your exe can change the value to any int it wants, but it only changes its copy of foo.

If you start up another exe, it too will load the dll and it too will get a copy of the section. That exe will have it's own copy of foo and it will initially be set to 5.

Read only sections behave differently so if you were to define foo as follows:

```
static const int foo = 5;
```

It would end up in a read only section of the dll and every exe would refer to the same foo in memory. It doesn't allow you to do what you're trying to do but it is nice thing to know as it saves memory. A good rule of thumb is to make everything `static` and `const` when possible.

Comment: This is correct but processes can access shared memory which is not really two processes sharing the same dll instance. But it's a work around

Comment: Would you recommend any alternative approaches? 
-Is it possible to launch 2 exe’s within the same process? 
-Does a child process allow any degree of memory access inheritance? -Would it be a good idea to make the second exe (currently a background service) a dll and load it from the main dll

Comment: @ScottFraser from what I have gathered, you have a complicated bit of logic stored in a DLL, you want to initialize an object in the DLL and use that object as a service for multiple child processes. Why not wrap the object in around an API and do RPC calls to interact with the API? Take a look at gRPC https://grpc.io/.